# Stochastic process, why this is that?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, differential-topology, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Let $W_t$ be a process such that:

$dW_t = (r+\pi* (\mu-r)) ) * W_t * dt + \pi * \sigma * W_t * d_{z_t}$

where $r, \pi, \mu, \sigma $ are constant,
$Z_t$ is the Geometric Brownian motion.

---

Applying Ito's Lemma on $logW_t$,
then we have:

$log W_t = \int_{0}^t (r+\pi * (\mu-r)-\frac{\pi^2 \sigma^2}{2})du + \int_{0}^{t}\pi \sigma dz_{u}$

**I dont know how come after applying Ito's lemma on the first equation will get to the second equation. Please help**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your source of confusion might be that the first equation is written in a differential form while the second one is written in an integral form.

---

Here is how to get the 2nd equation. Applying Ito Lemma to $logW_t$ we obtain
\begin{align}
d (\log W_t) &= \frac{1}{W_t}dW_t -\frac{1}{2 W_t^2}(dW_t)^2 \\
& = \frac{1}{W_t}( (r+\pi(\mu-r))W_t dt + \pi \sigma W_t d Z_t)\\
  & \quad -\frac{1}{2 W_t^2}(\pi^2 \sigma^2 W_t^2 dt) \\
& = \left(r + \pi(\mu-r) - \frac{1}{2}\pi^2\sigma^2\right)dt  + \pi \sigma d Z_t
\end{align}

Written in an integral form this becomes
$$ \log W_t = \int_0^t \left(r + \pi(\mu-r) - \frac{1}{2}\pi^2\sigma^2\right) du + \int_0^t \pi \sigma d Z_u $$

Comment: I C, this is much clear. The first line d log Wt is the Ito’s formulation right?

Comment: Yeah, the first line is the Ito's formula. The rest is just a bit of rearranging. If this answers your question, please accept the answer.

Comment: Thx, got it now.